# verb form - [have had no one to talk to] or [had no one to talk to]

Tags: tense

(1) Jack is very sad about losing all his savings. He **has had** no one to talk to until now.

(2) Jack is very sad about losing all his savings. He **had** no one to talk to until now.

Which tense of "to have" is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first one: "He **has** **had** no one to talk to until now."

It is *present perfect* tense, i.e., the action started in past and continued till now.